# How to use Django Cycle for displaying Two post on one row?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

Following code giving me the output of one post in one row, how can I change it to display two posts in one row ?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 mt-3 left">
      {% for post in disease_list %}
      <div class="card mb-4">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h6 class="card-title"><a href="{% url 'disease_detail' post.slug  %}"> {{ post.title }}</a></h6>
        </div>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Does Cycle method is good to implement here ? If Yes then how ?

Comment: Isn't it just a matter of making [row columns](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/#row-columns)? Bootstrap css can automatically stack your cards to have 2 per row.

Comment: It's not working using row-cols-2 :(

Comment: It should work if you do it correctly (a `row` div with `row-cols-2` then the loop with a `col` div then your `card` divs). Maybe your cards are too wide, what's the width set to? This is a css problem, so you should just debug the css in your browser tools.

Comment: Can you please show that by updating my code ?